# How to find if 1/n will be recurring decimal expansion?

Tags: decimal-expansion

How to determine if the expansion of $1/n$ would be a recurring decimal expansion or not? for example, $1/7 = 0.\overline{142857}$ but $1/8=0.125$.

So, how to find if $1/n$ would be a recurring decimal expansion or not?

Note: Here, $1/6=0.16666\ldots$ is not a recurring decimal expansion.

Comment: So, by "recurring", do you mean that every digit after the decimal point repeats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be recurring as long as the denominator (in lowest terms) does not have a factor $2$ or $5$.  There will be one non-recurring digit corresponding to the highest power of $2$ or $5$ in the denominator.  So $6$ has one factor two and $1/6$ has one non-recurring digit. $8$ has three factors of two and $1/8$ has three non-recurring digits.  $17$ has no factors of $2$ or $5$ and $1/17$ has no non-recurring digits.

Comment: can you please explain for 1/10? It has two and five as its factors, but is only 0.100... so, only one recurring digit..??

Comment: The number of non-recurring digits is the maximum of the power of $2$ and the power of $5$. So for $10=2^15^1$ the maximum power is $1$ and there is one non-recurring digit.